# Convert blob to text in a mysql export

Tags: mysql, export, blob

I'd have some blob data such as:

```
0x3333332c2044e963617269652c20356520e9746167650d0a53742d4c617572656e7420285175e9626563292048344e20334d390d0a
```

that I'd like to convert to text because the new database has text field instead of blobs and now it makes trouble with some accentuated characters.

Is there somekind of blob to string converter somewhere?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
CONVERT(blobname USING latin1)
```

Comment: Try that where? I said I have a mysql export a text file with inserts in it... Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the blob is.  For example, I've dealt with some blobs that could be represented as basic XML files.  Those would have been relatively easy to convert.  However, I dealt with other blobs that were image files.  If you tried to represent them as text you'd lose data.

What are in your blobs?

Answer (score 1):

Create your new database with your export, once done create your text column on the table, update that using a `CONVERT` drop the old column, renaming the old one if required.

Answer (score 0):

However if the data contains simple byte stream (that is, unstructured data, files, audio, video, whatever) and you need to represent them as pure ASCII you could change into a Base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

If using phpmyadmin, tick the box that says "Dump binary columns in hexadecimal notation (for example, "abc" becomes 0x616263)" at the bottom of the export page.